# File doesn't zip using 7zip command in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, 7zip

I am trying to zip a file in vb.net. I am using 7zip to do this. I am using the Process.Start method.
Here is the zip line of my code:

```
    Process.Start("C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe", "a -tzip" + (ChosenFile & "\" & "SavedFiles") + NewFileName1)
```

No error that I know of happens, however when I look through the path, I cannot find the zipped files.
ChosenFile & "\" & "SavedFiles" is the destination folder.
NewFileName1 is the file to be zipped

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404280(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: [ Note that 7-Zip has recently been updated: [Compression tool 7-Zip pwned, pain flows to top security, software tools](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2016/05/12/popular_zip_tool_7zip_pwned_pain_flows_to_top_security_software_tools/). ]

Comment: @Werdna thank you for responding. I've seen that page before and unfortunately I am using virtual basic 2008 which does not support System.IO.Compression.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Oh wow okay! Maybe I'll just use dotnetzip then!

Answer (score 0):

you must do a space after "-tzip" and u forgot use " to folders with spaces like that:

Process.Start("C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe", "a -tzip " & (ControlChars.Quote & ChosenFile & "\" & "SavedFiles"  & ControlChars.Quote) & " " & ControlChars.Quote & NewFileName1  & ControlChars.Quote &)

Answer (score -1):

Probably its obvious, but you have the rights to access those files with the user who runs the script?
Else, can you run the script manually step by step to debug where it fails?

Comment: Yes I can access the files. I have tried debugging and it doesn't seem to fail anywhere. It's just that I cannot find the zipped file when I look in the destination folder.